# Bash script run from Jenkins pipeline always fails after a phantom last line

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline

Our enterprise runs Jenkins 2.303.2.

I work on a shared library that we've been using for many builds for a long time.  We've used the "sh" pipeline step very often to run either standard command-line tools, or sometimes to execute scripts stored in the workspace of the code being built.

I'm now trying to do something that I've never done before, which is execute a shell script provided by the shared library, not the code being built.  I have a feeling that fact is a red herring.  I used the known strategy of storing the script in the "resources" directory, and using "libraryResource" and "writeFile" to store the file, and sh(chmod) to make it executable.  I verified at that point that I can execute it, because it shows me debug lines from within the script.

What's odd is that right after executing the "exit" line in the script, it fails with an odd "command not found" error, but it doesn't tell me what command it was trying to find.

This is a heavily elided excerpt from the build output:

```
+ chmod +x scriptname.sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./scriptname.sh ...
+ main ...
...
+ echo ''
+ return
+ exit 0
+ **** ****
.../script.sh: line 2: ****: command not found
```

This is the end of the script file:

```
main "$@"
exit 0
```

As you can see, it executes the "main" function, which does some work I've elided, which returns an empty string, and then exits the script.  The line with "exit" has a line return at the end of it, and that is the end of the file.  I've inspected the file that was written to the workspace (from the resources directory) to verify it is exactly as I expect.

This is an elided excerpt from the pipeline script:

```
def bashScript = libraryResource "scriptname.sh"
writeFile file: "./scriptname.sh", text: bashScript
sh("chmod +x scriptname.sh")

def scriptOutput = sh(returnStdout: true,
    script: "./scriptname.sh ...")
echo "scriptOutput[$scriptOutput]"
```

What might I be missing?

Update:

Right after the current "chmod" call, I added this:

```
sh("od -c checkmirrorsync.sh")
```

Here's the first couple of lines of that output:

```
0000000   #   !       /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n   s   e       t
0000020       -   x  \n  \n   m   a   i   n   (   )       {  \n  \t   i
```

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -x

main() {
```

Note that it executes well past this line, so that citing of "line 2" doesn't refer to lines in this script, but something else.

Comment: Try running `od scriptname.sh` and observe (1) whether there are weird unexpected invisible characters on line 2 at the end of your script, (2) whether line 2 of your script has a property new line sequence (compare it to line 1).

Comment: Thanks for responding. That didn't provide any clues. I'll update the post with more info.

Comment: Do you have arguments passed to the .sh script? And does an of them have white spaces?

Comment: Yes, it takes arguments. No, none of them have spaces. Logging in the script shows that all of the command-line arguments were received and set into expected variables.

Comment: Did you perhaps add the `sh(returnStatus: true)` option as well? It looks like you might need it according to the Jenkins docs https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/

Comment: No, I didn't add that, and that would conflict with returnStdout, which I actually need. I almost never use returnStatus in the script calls. I use returnStdout a great deal.

Comment: I'm thinking the exit code is leaking into Jenkins' pipeline causing it to terminate after the executed `sh` (which is probably why you are not seeing the echo from the pipe afterwards). You could try it out with the return status to conform. I am writing from mobile so I can't test it. If it's not that -- I'm out of ideas..

Answer (score 0):

Duh. I figured it out. I'm embarrassed it took this long. I should have remembered that a "command not found" error on line "2" from the "sh" pipeline step is not referring to line 2 of the script I was calling, but line 2 of the script I was sending to the "sh" pipeline step.  The fact that there WAS a line 2 of a single line I was sending was something I should have noticed.  The problem was that one of the parameters I was sending had a trailing CR, resulting in the next parameter being considered a potential command. Once I added a "trim()" call to that, it worked fine.